# chromakey: ffmpeg green color video removal

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-processing, chromakey

I am using ffmpeg on Mac to remove green background of video and add other background as image it is converting properly the video but auido is missing. I am using below command.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x3BBD1E:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 10):

I solved it my own.

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x3BBD1E:0.1:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[o]" -map [o] -map 1:a output.mp4
```

we need to add flags for audio.

Comment: Working well. One note - the resolution of the bg.jpg should be the same as video

Answer (score 0):

Once a map switch is added, only mapped streams are included. Add `-map 1:a? -c:a copy`